# Commerce module: Why this commerce_order_ui_form_commerce_order_ui_order_form_alter won't work?

Tags: forms, commerce

I have this commerce order, and I want to hook into it when an administrator review the order (edit it to set it as complete, canceled, or whatever state).

I want at that moment to use a specific field to check using ajax if the name I'm typing in a specific field, already exists as a username.

So I checked out how it works the [username_check module](https://www.drupal.org/project/username_check), and found that it does add that automatic checking using ajax. It does that check when the user types her desired username at the register form.

**How may I adapt it in order to use that functionality for other fields?**

The field machine name is `field_commerce_username`

I've looked into [commerce_order.api](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order.api.php/DC), at [hook_form_alter api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), [commerce_order_ui](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order_ui.module/7) and specially [commerce_order_ui_form_commerce_order_ui_order_form_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order_ui.module/function/commerce_order_ui_form_commerce_order_ui_order_form_alter/7) in order to know what to do.

**The username_check module uses hook_form_alter:**

```
function username_check_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form) {
  $mode     = variable_get('username_check_mode', 'auto');
  if($mode != 'off'){
    _username_check_profile_load_resources($mode);
    $form['account']['name']['#field_suffix'] = '<span id="profile-check-informer">&nbsp;</span>';
    $form['account']['name']['#suffix'] = '<div id="profile-check-message"></div>'; 
  }
```

**So, I thought in doing something like this:**

```
function commerce_order_ui_form_commerce_order_ui_order_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $mode     = variable_get('username_check_mode', 'auto');
  if($mode != 'off'){
    _username_check_profile_load_resources($mode);
    $form['element']['#field_name'] = 'commerce_customer_profile';
    }
}
```

Now, if I try to add that example code to the username_check.module (just for testing purposes), I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare commerce_order_ui_form_commerce_order_ui_order_form_alter() in /home/sitio/public_html/sites/all/modules/username_check/username_check.module on line 75
```

(75 line if where I declare my function).

***I just need to be pointed to the right direction here, why is this error?***

commerce_order_ui_form_commerce_order_ui_order_form_alter() wasn't declared before in the file... and it won't work even if I comment all _form_alter functions in the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing by your rep that you already know most of the following but it pays to check:

1. Hooks can only exist once per module
2. Hooks must begin with the module name

So this means `commerce_order_ui_form_commerce_order_ui_order_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)` won't work inside username_check.module

If you really want to put the code inside the username_check module call it:

`username_check_form_commerce_order_ui_order_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)`

---

[edit:]

Of course, you shouldn't put test code inside an existing module.  The best way to test code is to [make your own custom module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7), which is pretty easy once you get the hang of it.

Comment: And of course clear your cache before testing =)